# If $\limsup_n x_n\leq M$ then there exists a subsequence $\{y_{n}\}$ such that $ y_{n}\leq y_{n+1}$ and $ y_n\leq M$, $\forall n $

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limsup-and-liminf

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a sequence such that
$$
\limsup_n x_n\leq M<\infty
$$
Can we say theres exist a subsequence $\{y_{n}\}$ of $\{x_n\}$ such that
$$
y_{n}\leq y_{n+1}\qquad \forall n
$$
And
$$
y_n\leq M\qquad \forall n
$$

Comment: What if $x_n$ is a strictly decreasing convergent sequence?

Comment: No. Consider the sequence $1/n$